# Can i change radio button drawable in android for API < 21?

Tags: android, radio-button, material-design, selector, android-drawable

I am using **AppCompatRadioButton** and i want to use my custom drawable for that and i achieved this via code below but its working only for API >= 21.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**selector_custom_radio_buttons.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_done_single" android:state_checked="false" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_done_all" android:state_checked="true" />
</selector>
```

and then i set the radio buttons selector via style in activity theme

**Styles.xml**

```
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="ThemeNewsFeed" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/MyRadioButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyRadioButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/selector_custom_radio_buttons</item>
</style>
```

and here is activity in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".social.NewsFeedActivity"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeNewsFeed">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

**Note:** The problem is my custom drawable are working well on API 21 and greater but on API less then 21 , its showing default radio buttons drawable. so what should i do for lower API's ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Remove your AppCompatRadioButton style from activity theme and set directly to AppCompatRadioButton xml code like below

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     style="@style/MyRadioButtonStyle""/>
```

and in Style.xml

```
 <style name="MyRadioButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
        <item name="android:button">@drawable/selector_custom_radio_buttons</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted solution did not work for me. I'm Using AndroidX and targetting API 17. There's no need to create new style. Just replace

```
"android:button"
```

with

```
"app:buttonTint"
```

Comment: your solution is not enough. Because you can just use buttonTint with colors, not with drawable.

Comment: @oalpayli don't know what to tell you. I'm using this method in a current project to have drawables

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this is an old thread, but maybe other people stumbling on this very same issue might be helped with the below.  I'll give it a chance...

I too had the same problem with my application which is running with API 18.  I couldn't use `android:button="@null"` and `android:background="@drawable/<selector>"`.  That was only working from API21 onward.

My solution was to simply create a new class that was extending the RadioButton class, but to **not** inherit from `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton` but to simply inherit from `RadioButton` itself.

So, my "extended" class looked very, very simple:

**NOT** this:

```
public class RadioButtonZed extends  androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton {
    public RadioButtonZed(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
    }
}
```

but this:

```
@SuppressLint("AppCompatCustomView")
public class RadioButtonZed extends RadioButton {
    public RadioButtonZed(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
}
```

Mind the `@SuppressLint("AppCompatCustomView")` to avoid complains by the AS IDE.

The only thing I had to do, was to add one and only one constructor in my "own" radio button class...

In my XML file, I changed this:

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rb_way_too_much"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_level_1"
    android:background="@drawable/radio"
    android:button="@null"
    tools:checked="true" />
```

to this:

```
<be.geertvancompernolle.mycustomradiobutton.RadioButtonZed
    android:id="@+id/rb_way_too_much"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_level_1"
    android:background="@drawable/radio"
    android:button="@null"
    tools:checked="true" />
```

And this time, the `@null` and `@drawable/radio` were working as expected.

In the end, instead of this (mind the original button image circle "inside" my button image):

[image]

and this:

[image]

I now have this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

Exactly what I want!